# My header container is not 100% width and height.

Tags: html, css

Here you can see what i mean : https://i.gyazo.com/213882546f564fac7d33e9939c1e684d.png

Im trying to make my header be 100% width and height. I first thought i was something to do with body native 8px margin.. so i added

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

but no success.
here is css

```
#container {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 350px;
background-image: url("../images/banner2.svg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: @theGleep uploaded for you to check, http://hermods.aphhorses.se/

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question. If the site you linked to is blocked or goes away then this question loses all value to future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your above code is perfectly valid, and will cause the container to occupy 100% of the page.

This can be seen in the example below:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

If you are not seeing the same result, usually it can only be down to one of three reasons:

1. You have declarations with higher **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)** that are overriding your above rules.
2. You have cached the old CSS. To forcibly clear your cache, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking on the `Refresh` icon.
3. You have an incorrect HTML structure, and your rules aren't being applied correctly. You can validate your HTML and CSS at **[the W3 HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org)** and the **[W3 CSS Validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)**.

In your **particular** case, the image **itself** has a white border - removing this border in the image will fix the problem, as the element itself is already occupying the full width of the page.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Perhaps you could check http://hermods.aphhorses.se/ i ran the validator and  it showed no error and i clear the cache and still no success.. perhaps you see something i don't see.

Comment: Looking into it, your **code** isn't the problem, but rather your **image**. If you look into http://hermods.aphhorses.se/images/banner2.svg, you'll see that your image **itself** actually contains a white border. Removing this will solve your problem, as the element itself runs to the full width of the page :)

Comment: wow... thanks alot.. i really had no idea it had borders into it.. thanks alot for help :D